# ¿Cómo eliminar datos de una lista de strings y solo dejar los datos que sean números?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Cordial saludo:

Tengo una lista de strings de la siguiente forma:

```
 l = ['hola como estas','3.4','5.7','mundo','6.7','cuesta 440$','9.8']
```

Y quiero eliminar las palabras y dejar solo los números, algo así:

```
 L = ['3.4','5.7','6.7','9.8']
```

O así:

```
 L = [3.4 , 5.7, 6.7 , 9.8]
```

¿Cómo lo podría hacer de un modo general para cualquier lista que se presente con otras palabras y otras posiciones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En mi opinión la forma más sencilla es intentado hacer la conversión a `float` y descartando los demás:

```
>>> l = ['hola como estas','3.4','5.7','mundo','6.7','cuesta 440$','9.8']
>>> l2 = []
>>> l3 = []
>>> for elem in l:
...     try:
...         l2.append(float(elem))
...     except ValueError:
...         l3.append(elem)
...
>>> l2
[3.4, 5.7, 6.7, 9.8]
>>> l3
['hola', 'mundo', 'python']
```

De esta manera tiene en `l2` la lista con los números y en `l3` la lista con los demás si es que los necesitas para después.

Si necesitas algo más general podrías crear una función:

```
def es_numero(n):
    try:
        float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Ahora, podrías usar esto:

```
>>> for elem in l:
...     if es_numero(elem):
...         l2.append(float(elem))
...     else:             
...         l3.append(elem)
...         
>>> l2
[3.4, 5.7, 6.7, 9.8]
>>> l3
['hola', 'mundo', 'python']
```

Si no necesitas los demás elementos, podrías usar simplemente una lista de comprehensión usando la función `es_numero`:

```
>>> l2 = [float(num) for num in l if es_numero(num)]
>>> l2
[3.4, 5.7, 6.7, 9.8]
```

O si te quieres poner más elegante:

```
>>> l2 = map(float, filter(es_numero, l))
>>> l2
[3.4, 5.7, 6.7, 9.8]
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido tu explicación.

Comment: @YeisonOrdoñez de nada, no olvides marcarla como aceptada a la izquierda de mi pregunta, de esta forma tu respuesta queda como resuelta. Saludos!

Comment: disculpa no sabia, de todas formas muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

La técnica que te ha explicado @César es el modo tradicional de usar el constructor `float` para convertir de cadena a número. Pero a veces lo ideal para trabajar con números de coma fija es usar el tipo `decimal` para no perder precisión o para poder trabajar con números mayores o menores de lo que acepta el tipo `double` de `C` en el que se basa `float`.

Para convertir la lista de cadenas a números *decimal* podemos hacerlo usando el contexto `ExtendedContext` de la siguiente manera:

```
from decimal import (Decimal, localcontext, ExtendedContext)

l = ['hola como estas','3.4','5.7','mundo','6.7','cuesta 440$','9.8']

# Añadimos otras cadenas que podrían ser problemáticas con float
l += ["infinity", "nan", "1e455", "1.00000000000000002"]

with localcontext(ExtendedContext):
    l2 = [ x for x in (Decimal(s) for s in l)
                 if x.is_finite() ]

print(l2)
```

Y como resultado:

```
[Decimal('3.4'),
 Decimal('5.7'),
 Decimal('6.7'),
 Decimal('9.8'),
 Decimal('1E+455'),
 Decimal('1.00000000000000002')]
```